# How to link from html site to any site in view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have got my main page in project_name/public/index.html. I want to link from index.html site to controller view located in project_name/app/views/my_controller

How can I recive that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to just use an `a ref` link

`<a ref="/my_controller">Link Text</a>`

Comment: In that way doesn't work, site shows only link but when I click on it nothing happens.

On my own I tried in that way:

    <a href="/app/views/my_controller/index.html.erb"> Link </a>

but browser shows:

> Routing error
> 
> No route matches [GET] "/app/views/my_controller/index.html.erb"
> 
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes. 

I added `get '/app/views/my_controller/index'` and I did `rake routes` but still I have same problem.

Comment: I did <a href="/my_controller"> and it works. Thanks